# Permissions for android application in blackberry

Tags: android, blackberry, android-permissions, blackberry-10, permission-denied

My blackberry phone version is 10.3.2. I installed an android application on it. The application needs permission to send sms. But I dont see any option to enable the permission application permission. 
 In android, the application even requests for permission on launch, but not for blackberry. 
 Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Android apps run on BlackBerry 10 devices cannot access some of the BlackBerry services like emails, SMS or contacts, that's why you don't even see the permission in `Settings -> Security and Privacy -> Application Permissions -> YourSmsAppName`. Most of the permissions for Android apps are granted and cannot be revoked on BlackBerry 10, only the `Run When Minimized` permission can be revoked.

If you install any Android Launcher app on your BlackBerry 10, you'll be able to access the Android Settings app, you'll be able to navigate to `Settings -> Apps -> YourSmsAppName` and see that the SMS permission is there indeed, but there's no way to disable it (or enable it in your case, it's already enabled).

I had a situation where I needed one of my Android app to get access to BlackBerry 10 emails and SMS, and the only solution I found was to build a BlackBerry 10 companion app that exchange data through a local socket on the phone, you won't be able to do that if you don't have control (of code) of both Android and BlackBerry 10 apps.